# INSERT, and get the auto-incremented value

Tags: sql, derby, javadb

Consider the following table:

```
create table language (
    id integer generated always as identity (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    name long varchar,
    constraint language_pk primary key (id)
);
```

To which I'd insert an entry this way.

```
insert into language(name) values ('value');
```

How does one know what value for `id` was created? Just doing a SELECT using the `name` field is not valid, because there can be duplicate entries.

Comment: In Firebird I know you can use `Returning ID` to have it insert and return the new value for a column.  Others should have something similar, though I'm not familiar personally with Derby.

Comment: I use Derby/Java DB as described in the tags

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131064/get-id-of-last-inserted-record-in-oracle-db

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5576152/getting-id-of-record-just-inserted

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353343/getting-last-inserted-id

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590927/get-new-sql-record-id

Vote to close.

Comment: None of those answers seem solve this specific problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through plain SQL:

```
 insert into language(name) values ('value');
 SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL();
```

See the manual for details: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/rrefidentityvallocal.html

When doing this from a Java class (through JDBC) you can use [getGeneratedKeys()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) after "requesting" them with the approriate [executeUpdate()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method.

Comment: Your answer in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4894754/retrieve-id-of-record-just-inserted-into-a-java-db-derby-database

Answer (score 1):

You use the JDBC method

```
st.execute(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
ResultSet keys = st.getGeneratedKeys();
```

as documented in the [Derby manual](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.0/manuals/reference/sqlj229.html).

See also Javadocs: [DatabaseMetaData#supportsGetGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#supportsGetGeneratedKeys%28%29)
and [Statement#getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

You could execute this statement (NB, not 100% sure this syntax is correct for Derby:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id FROM language ORDER BY id DESC
```

To find the last inserted ID.

Alternative for Derby:

```
SELECT MAX(id) from language
```

Obviously this will only be accurate if no other inserts (including inserts by other users) have happened between your insert and select.

See also this [discussion](http://old.nabble.com/Top-1---Limit-1-td6315512.html):

Comment: Not safe in multiuser enviroment - if two users add record at the same time you might get wrong ID back.

Comment: @ain: Exactly, as I call out in the answer.

Comment: This will do for my specific program (thank you!) but it's interesting, what @ain says

Comment: @xan Well, you added/edited it after my comment? It wasn't there when I wrote my comment...

Comment: My comment on other inserts affecting the ID returned to you was there from the start. After reading your comment I added the specific note on other users interacting with the table as it is a very valid point.